# normal connection on immersed hypersurface vanishing

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am studying Riemannian geometry using Do Carmo's book.
I am learning about isometric immersions right now, and I got stuck with the following claim about Codazzi's equation.

Let $f:M^n \to \overline M ^{n+m} $ be an immersion, with the metric of $M$ being the one iduced from $\overline M$.

In this situation we can write $T_p \overline M = T_p M \oplus (T_p M)^{\bot}$.

We can also split the connection $\overline\nabla$ of $\overline M$  to its tangential and normal components.

This gives rise to the normal connection, defined on the normal bundle by $$\nabla^{\bot}_X\eta = \text{the normal component of } \overline\nabla_X\eta$$
where $X\in \mathcal X(M)$ and $\eta \in \mathcal X(M)^{\bot}$.

Let $X,Y,Z \in \mathcal X(M)$ and $\eta \in \mathcal X(M)^{\bot}$.
Codazzi's equation is
$$ <\overline R(X,Y)Z, \eta> = (\overline\nabla_Y B)(X, Z, \eta) - (\overline\nabla_X B)(Y, Z, \eta)$$
where $B(X, Y, \eta) = <B(X, Y), \eta>$ and $B(X, Y)$ is the normal component of $\overline\nabla_X Y$.

Now, if $\overline M$ has constant sectional curvature, the curvature tensor is 0, so Codazzi's equation can be rewritten as
$$(\overline\nabla_Y B)(X, Z, \eta) = (\overline\nabla_X B)(Y, Z, \eta)$$

Up until here I understood everything.
Now the author claims that if, in addition $M$ is a hypersurface (i.e. the codimension of the immersion is 1) then $\nabla^{\bot}_X\eta = 0$.
This again allows to again rewrite the equation in another form.

My question is, why is that if $\overline M$ has constant sectional curvature and the codimension of $M$ in $\overline M$ is 1 then $\nabla^{\bot}_X\eta = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to see if $\eta$ has length $1$, for then, for $X$ tangent to $M$,
$$X\langle \eta, \eta\rangle = 0 = 2\langle \eta ,\bar{\nabla}_X \eta\rangle$$

(Note that this reasoning, in fact, only works in codimension $1$).

I don't think this is true in general, though I may have forgotten something during the years.

Comment: Yeah, I know it holds for the case where $\eta$ is a unit normal but the author never mentions that is has to be the case. Maybe its implied to be obvious but I'm not sure.